# Android GestureDetector double tap is never fired

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I have a custom `DialogFragment` which contains a custom `ScrollView` which has some images. When the user makes double tap I want to change the zoom of images. I did this in `onCreateDialog`

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_document);

    scrollViewContainer = (ObservableScrollView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewContainer);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureListener());

    scrollViewContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}
```

And the `GestureListener` class is

```
private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    // event when double tap occurs
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        //double tap fired.
        if (mScaleFactor != 1.f) {
            mScaleFactor = mTempScaleFactor = 1f;
        } else {
            mScaleFactor = mTempScaleFactor = 2f;
        }
        prepareForZoom(e.getX(0), e.getY(0));
        setZoom();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried to add `return getActivity().onTouchEvent(event);` in `OnTouch` method or/and `v.dispatchTouchEvent(event)` but didn't work.

I mention that `onDown` method is fired from time to time.

Can I catch `onDoubleTap` event somehow?

### Problem solved

I solved the problem by adding a `LinearLayout` in `ScrollView` and then `setOnTouchListener` on this `Layout`.

Comment: where did you call `GestureDetector#setOnDoubleTapListener`?

Comment: I didn't. I thought that it will be done by `GestureDetector`. In the pas I did the same for an activity and I shouldn't worry about `setOnDoubleTapListener` it works perfect.

Comment: right, it is done in `GestureDetector(Context context, OnGestureListener listener, Handler handler)`